# Why is my laptop main screen backlight not working?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, brightness

I'm using a live USB drive and I'm trying to install Ubuntu 22.04 on my Dell Precision 7710 with Nvidia Quadro M3000M GPU and I'm facing a weird problem. My current graphics setup consists of two external monitors along with the integrated laptop screen.

The problem is that the backlight on the laptop screen seems to not be working. The screen is really dark and I can just barely see what's in it. In doing some research I found out about `/sys/class/backlight/nv_backlight/` and when I perform a `cat /sys/class/backlight/nv_backlight/actual_brightness` I get `0` and the real problem is that I also get `0` when I execute `cat /sys/class/backlight/nv_backlight/max_brightness`.

On the other hand, if I boot the laptop and chose **Ubuntu (safe graphics)** from the grub menu then the laptop display works just fine but I lose the external displays. In this mode, I have `/sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/` instead and the actual brightness is `100`. Another thing I notice in this mode is that there is a brightness slider below the volume slider. It doesn't work, but it is there.

What is going on and how can I fix this? I don't want to go ahead and install Ubuntu without figuring this out first.

*I don't care about the Nvidia drivers, I'm not using this laptop for gaming or any of that stuff, I just need my three monitors, so I don't really care how to solve this as long as I have visible image on the three. I mention this just in case there is a solution that doesn't involve the Nvidia drivers.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was solved by installing the driver v418 since my particular system doesn't work well with any other driver version.
[image]

Everything is working perfectly now.